# How do I Combine BDD and TDD in a MVC Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

We are trying to combine BDD and TDD approach in our new project.

Using Specflow, NUnit and WatiN in our MVC3 project, I'm trying to follow the logic of Outside-in process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx
I would like to know what I’m trying to do is correct.

```
Feature: Commit RPI, As any user, I want to commit all RPI values

Scenario: Commit RPI values, Given I am in the RPI screen And I have entered RPI values

| Year | Month | RPI Value |    
| 2012 | 1     | 1.2       |
```

When I want to commit RPI values, then RPI values should be committed

Acceptance tests will be as below:

```
[Given(@"I am in the RPI screen")]    
public void GivenIAmInTheRPIScreen()    
{    
    WebBrowser.Current.GoTo("http://localhost:8010/");    //WebBrowser is the instance of Internet Explorer created by WatiN
    Assert.AreEqual(WebBrowser.Current.Title, "RPI List");
}

***This step will initially fail as there will not be any RPI List screen. So, I’ll go to the web project, create a controller and view. When I run the test again, WatiN will be able to open up the screen and pass the test.***

[Given(@"I have entered RPI values")]    
public void GivenIHaveEnteredRPIValues(Table tblRPI)
{    
    if (tblRPI.Rows.Count > 0)   
    {
        var txtYear = (TextField) WebBrowser.Current.Elements.First(Find.ById("txtRPIYear"));

        if (txtYear != null) 
           txtYear.Value = tblRPI.Rows[0]["Year"];

        var txtMonth = (TextField)WebBrowser.Current.Elements.First(Find.ById("txtRPIMonth"));

        if (txtMonth != null)
            txtMonth.Value = tblRPI.Rows[0]["Month"];

        var txtValue = (TextField)WebBrowser.Current.Elements.First(Find.ById("txtRPIValue"));

        if (txtValue != null)
            txtValue.Value = tblRPI.Rows[0]["RPI Value"];
    }
    else    
    {
        Assert.True(false);
    }
}

[When(@"I want to commit RPI values")]    
public void WhenIWantToCommitRPIValues()
{

   var btnCommitValues = (Button)WebBrowser.Current.Elements.First(Find.ById("btnCommitValues"));

   if (btnCommitValues != null)
   {
       btnCommitValues.Focus();
   }
   else
   {
       Assert.IsTrue(btnCommitValues != null);
   }
}

[Then(@"RPI values should be committed")]
public void ThenRPIValuesShouldBeCommitted()
{
    var btnCommitValues = (Button)WebBrowser.Current.Elements.First(Find.ById("btnCommitValues"));

    if (btnCommitValues != null)
    {
        btnCommitValues.Click();
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(btnCommitValues != null);    
    }
}
```

***This step will fail as there will not be any logic to commit the values. At this stage, I will stop BDD and go ahead to write my unit test cases for the commit logic. I will write various test cases using NUnit, make them pass so that when I come back to the acceptanace test, there will be a logic to commit RPI values which would have passed my unit tests and the acceptance test will now pass.***

My question is almost similar to this [How do specflow features link to unit tests in asp.net webforms projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013734/how-do-specflow-features-link-to-unit-tests-in-asp-net-webforms-projects)

If you have done similar work using SpecFlow, NUnit and MVC, could you please share your thoughts. .

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what the question is, or what problem you are struggling with. What I am hearing is "is writing a failing BDD acceptance test first, then TDD unit tests to implement the feature, a valid approach for MVC". Are you asking whether the process is right, or having specific problems with that approach?

Comment: Thanks Mathias. Yes, I'm asking whether the process is right. I have mentioned this at the beginning of my post."I would like to know what I’m trying to do is correct.". May be, I should have been more clearer. I'm very new to both TDD and BDD. I just want to know if my approach is correct. Thanks for your feedback